# Terraform deletes the previous instance when you re-run it to create new

Tags: terraform, vsphere

I'm new to terraform and using version v0.12.20. I noticed it is deleting the existing resource as soon as I re-run it to create a new one. For instance if I create 10 vms in a certain env and want to create 5 new, it should simply create new ones detecting a change, rather than deleting previous ones and creating new ones.

```
 resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "test_vms" {
      name = "${var.environment_test}${count.index + 1}"
      resource_pool_id = data.vsphere_compute_cluster.cluster.resource_pool_id
      datastore_id     = "${element(data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.*.id, count.index)}"

      num_cpus         = var.cpu
      count            = var.count
      memory           = var.memory
      guest_id         = "ubuntu64Guest"
      folder           = var.vmfolder
      cpu_hot_add_enabled    = var.cpu_hot_add_enabled
      memory_hot_add_enabled = var.memory_hot_add_enabled
      scsi_type        = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.scsi_type
      wait_for_guest_net_timeout = -1

      network_interface {
         network_id    = data.vsphere_network.network[1].id
        adapter_type = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.network_interface_types[0]
      }


      disk {
        label            = "disk0"
         size            = "${var.disk_size}"
        thin_provisioned = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks.0.thin_provisioned
      }

      clone {
        template_uuid = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.id

        customize {
          linux_options {
            host_name     =  "${var.environment_test}${count.index + 1}"
            domain       = var.vmdomain
          }

          network_interface {
              ipv4_address =   "${var.ips_test}${var.test_index + count.index}"
               ipv4_netmask =  "${var.netmask_app}"
         }
     dns_server_list = "${var.dns_server_list}"
             dns_suffix_list = "${var.dns_suffix_list}"

             ipv4_gateway = "${var.gateway_app}"
        }

          }

    }
```

Output of terraform plan -

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # vsphere_virtual_machine.small_vm[0] must be replaced
-/+ resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "test_vm" {

      ~ memory_share_count                      = 81920 -> (known after apply)
        memory_share_level                      = "normal"
        migrate_wait_timeout                    = 30
      ~ name                                    = "tests01" -> "testm01

      ~ clone {


              ~ linux_options {
                    domain       = "X.X.X.X."
                  ~ host_name    = "tests01" -> "testm01" # forces replacement
                    hw_clock_utc = true
                }

              ~ network_interface {
                  - dns_server_list = [] -> null
                  ~ ipv4_address    = "X.X.X.X" -> "X.X.X.X" # forces replacement
                    ipv4_netmask    = 24
                  - ipv6_netmask    = 0 -> null
```

Comment: Hello! Could you please edit your question to include the output from `terraform plan` where you are seeing the unexpected planned changes? Hopefully by seeing that I or someone else can explain the reason for what Terraform is doing and what you might to to influence Terraform to make a different plan.

Comment: @MartinAtkins Thanks very much for your response.

Comment: I have added the output of terraform plan above. I created a vm named tests01 and re-ran the script to create a new one named testm01 but as you can see the script replaces the old vm and assigns new IP address to it. I would rather expect it to create a new vm with new IP address. How can that be achieved?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like not all of the information is in the question here. I'm not sure where `tests` and `testm` are coming from. Are you changing the value of `var.environment_test`? Could you include more of your configuration in the question so I can see what changed to make `tests` become `testm`?

Comment: I'm changing the value of var.environment_test. Initially I ran the script with environment_test value as tests and later I modified the value of environment_test to testm. I was expecting a new vm testm01 would be created without wiping out the previous one but actually previous one gets deleted and new one is formed. We build an env with few vms and keep creating new ones as and when needed. For instance if I create 50 vms in an env and few days later I want to create few more, I should modify the vars with new vm names & IPs, it shouldn't delete the previous ones and just create new ones.

Comment: @MartinAtkins Please let me know if there is a solution for the above. Thanks in advance

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Not want to delete anything instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Terraform is not designed for this sort of use-case where you only want to create new things and then leave them to be managed elsewhere. Instead, Terraform's model is management of long-lived objects where you may need to make changes to them over time still in Terraform.

Internally, Terraform associates every resource instance declared in your configuration with a remote object in the vendor's remote API. In your case, each of the `vsphere_virtual_machine.test_vm` instances (which Terraform is calling `vsphere_virtual_machine.small_vm[0]`, `vsphere_virtual_machine.small_vm[1]`, etc depending on your value of `count`) is associated with one real virtual machine in vSphere, and when you later make changes to the configuration Terraform will plan to update or replace the remote objects in order to make the remote system match the changes in the configuration.

I think the closest usage pattern to what you want to achieve here would be to define an input variable that is a map of descriptions of virtual machines that should exist, like this:

```
variable "virtual_machines" {
  type = map(object({
    num_cpus = number
  }))

  default = {
    tests01 = {
      num_cpus = 2
    }
    testm01 = {
      num_cpus = 1
    }
  }
}
```

I've included this `num_cpus` attribute in the objects just to illustrate how you can define attributes to represent values other than the name that might need to differ between the virtual machines. (If you don't currently need these virtual machines to differ in any way *other than* their names, you can set the type to `map(object({}))` to use empty objects for now, so you have room for expansion later.)

With this variable you can then use `for_each` instead of `count` to tell Terraform to make one virtual machine instance per element in the `var.virtual_machines` map:

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "test_vms" {
  for_each = var.virtual_machines

  name             = each.key
  resource_pool_id = data.vsphere_compute_cluster.cluster.resource_pool_id
  datastore_id     = data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id

  num_cpus                   = each.value.num_cpus
  memory                     = var.memory
  guest_id                   = "ubuntu64Guest"
  folder                     = var.vmfolder
  cpu_hot_add_enabled        = var.cpu_hot_add_enabled
  memory_hot_add_enabled     = var.memory_hot_add_enabled
  scsi_type                  = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.scsi_type
  wait_for_guest_net_timeout = -1

  network_interface {
    network_id   = data.vsphere_network.network[1].id
    adapter_type = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.network_interface_types[0]
  }

  disk {
    label            = "disk0"
    size             = var.disk_size
    thin_provisioned = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.disks[0].thin_provisioned
  }

  clone {
    template_uuid = data.vsphere_virtual_machine.template.id

    customize {
      dns_server_list = var.dns_server_list
      dns_suffix_list = var.dns_suffix_list

      ipv4_gateway = var.gateway_app

      linux_options {
        host_name = each.key
        domain    = var.vmdomain
      }

      network_interface {
        ipv4_address = "${var.ips_test}${var.test_index + count.index}"
        ipv4_netmask = var.netmask_app
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Inside the `resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "test_vms"` block I used `each.key` to access each key from `var.virtual_machines` (the virtual machine names, in this case) and `each.value` to access the corresponding object that contains a `num_cpus` attribute.

Given the default value of `var.virtual_machines` I declared above, Terraform will interpret this as a request to create two virtual machines with the following tracking addresses:

- `vsphere_virtual_machine.test_vms["tests01"]` (with two CPUs)
- `vsphere_virtual_machine.test_vms["testm01"]` (with one CPU)

Notice that Terraform is using the keys from the map to track each individual instance of this resource. When you want to add a new virtual machine without disturbing the others, you can add a new entry to the value of `var.virtual_machines`, *leaving all of the existing elements alone*. Each time you add a new element to that map and run `terraform apply` again Terraform will plan to create a new virtual machine instance. Similarly, if you remove or edit an entry in that map then Terraform will plan to destroy or update/replace the corresponding virtual machine.

---

For the problem of *environments* in particular, rather than individual virtual machines, note that usually it's best to create a separate Terraform configuration per environment so that you can update each one separately and not risk updates to one making unintended changes to another.

The common approach for that is to use the configuration you've already written as a [shared module](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/modules.html), and then for each new environment you want to create you can write a small new configuration that contains only a single call to that module with the settings that apply to that specific environment:

```
module "environment1" {
  # This is a relative path to whatever directory contains
  # the module whose configuration we've been discussing so far.
  source = "../../modules/environment"

  virtual_machines = {
    env1foo = {
      num_cpus = 2
    }
    env1bar = {
      num_cpus = 2
    }
  }

  vmfolder            = "example"
  cpu_hot_add_enabled = false
  # (and so on, for all of the other environment-specific variables
  # you need to override)
}
```

Each separate Terraform module is a separate directory, so you might shape your directory structure something like this, for example:

```
- environments/
  - environment1/
    - environment.tf
  - environment2/
    - environment.tf
- modules
  - environment
    - variables.tf
    - main.tf
    - (etc)
```

To create a new environment, you'd make a new subdirectory of `environments` and write a new `environment.tf` in there, then switch into that directory and run Terraform:

```
cd environments/environment1
terraform init
terraform apply
```

Terraform tracks the objects for each configuration separately in a separate [state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/index.html) snapshot, so by having a separate configuration directory for each you can work on each environment separately without involving any configuration from the others. However, each of them will share the same "environment" module, and so they'll all be built from the same definition and you can update that shared "environment" module any time you want to make a change that should apply across all of your environments.

Comment: Thanks for your response but the problem is that terraform is deleting the resource when it detects a change. I want to create an env with 100 vms and the script I've mentioned is used to acheive that. For instance if I want to expand it to 102 vms and re-run the script with a change, it will replace the previous instances and then create 2 new. I don't want my other vms to be deleted or replaced. Infact I don't want to use terraform for any vm deletion, we can handle that manually. I would only like to use it to keep expanding the env.